# Number of 3 element subsets of ${1,2,...,n}$ with a certain property.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

Given the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, I want to count the number of three-element subsets $\{x,y,z\}$ such that $|x-y|=1$ or $|x-z| = 1$ or $|y-z|=1$. I'm not familiar with how to deal with the "inclusive or" in a counting problem.

As someone pointed out, we can equivalently count the number of triples $\{x,y,z\}$ such that $|x-y|>1$ and $|x-z|>1$ and $|y-z|>1$.

Comment: It's easier to count the complement, since ands are easier to deal with than ors.

Comment: You can first impose a condition like $x \leq y \leq z$ and make the condition easier,  that is either $y - x = 1$ or $z - y = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the complement: count the number of three-element subsets $\{x,y,z\}$ $1\leq x<y<z\leq n$ such that $s:=y-x\geq 2$ and $t:=z-y\geq 2$
where $x+s+t\leq n$. It follows that counting the complement is the same as finding the number of non-negative integer solutions of the equation
$$A+B+C+D=n-5$$
where $A:=x-1$, $B=s-2$, $C=t-2$. By [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two), this number is $\binom{n-5+3}{3}=\binom{n-2}{3}$. Hence the answer is
$$\binom{n}{3}-\binom{n-2}{3}=(n-2)^2.$$

Comment: Thank you, I think this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need a pair of successive integers and an arbitrary one. And then subtract those three integers that have two successive ones. That likes Inc-Exc Principle. You have $n-1$ choices for successive ones and then have $n-2$ choices for that arbitrary one. For subtracting, we know there successive integers have two successive ones that there is $n-2$ ones. So the answer is:
$$(n-1)(n-2) - (n-2) = (n-2)^2$$

Comment: Nice explanation, makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score -3):

I think your first have to built a two elements subset of two consecutive integers. There is $n - 1$ ways to do. Then, you chose the last element between the $n - 2$ elements that remain. Finally there is $(n - 1)(n - 2)$ such subsets.

Comment: This cant be the solution since the number of three element subsets is ${n \choose 3} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}< (n-1)(n-2)$ at least for $n< 6$. I do agree that starting with two-element subsets of consecutive integers is a good idea.

Comment: This way you count a different subset many times.  For example,  if you choose $1,2$ then $3$ is the same as you chose $2,3$ first then $1$.

Comment: Oh, so this is the number of ordered pairs with the property. I was hoping to count sets instead. Looks like you can subtract n-2 to remove duplicates.

Comment: I totally agree with it. The idea is now to know how many times we count each set. The answer is the number of time we could ordered a three elements subset and is $3!$ because it's the number of one to one correspondances from a set to itself. According to me, the final answer is $\frac{(n - 1)(n - 2)}{6}$